# Where does PHP include_path master value come from?

Tags: php, centos5

Via phpinfo, I get the following for include_path *Master Value*.

```
.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
```

It does not appear to be set anywhere... php ini has all include_path(s) commented out, my apps do not set it manually, apache conf/php conf/other assorted conf's/ini's do not set it, no results when searching for set_include_path or phpvalue or ini_set, etc.

Any ideas where else "include_path" might be set? I am asking specifically about master value.

(I am on CentOS 5.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's configured at build time. You can see how your PHP installation was configured by looking at the *Configure Command* in the output from `phpinfo();`

For more information on PHP configure options see [PHP Installation and Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php). Also [php-build — Builds multiple versions of PHP](https://github.com/CHH/php-build) might be of help or interest.

#### Note for Ubuntu users

You won't find the configure command in the phpinfo output, see [this bug marked as invalid](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/516061). Here are some links to code mentioned in the bug report.

- ["puruse" debian/rules](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/quantal/php5/quantal/view/head:/debian/rules)
- [052-phpinfo_no_configure.patch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/quantal/php5/quantal/view/head:/debian/patches/052-phpinfo_no_configure.patch)

#### Example Configure Command from phpinfo():

`Configure Command => './configure' '--build=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=i686-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=i386-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-png' '--with-pspell' '--with-expat-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-track-vars' '--enable-trans-sid' '--enable-yp' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-memory-limit' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dbx' '--enable-dio' '--with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbstr-enc-trans' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-ncurses=shared' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib/mysql/mysql_config' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-dom-xslt=/usr' '--with-dom-exslt=/usr' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/lib/mysql/mysql_config' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--enable-dbase=shared'`

Answer (score 2):

From php.ini file

> ; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
>   ; http://php.net/include-path

and yours above seems to be adding PHP's directory, so current directory; pear; PHP (PHP's home) directory

You can also check Apache confs or your .htaccess file to see if you're setting it there.

Comment: Like I said, neither php ini nor apache confs have include_path commented out so it's definitely not from there; and I don't have anything in htaccess. Any other ideas?

Comment: I didn't mean it was taking from php.ini, I meant my comment was from there. If your php.ini and apache configs and htaccess ARE NOT being accessed. Then what I posted above is the default for PHP, and that's where it's coming from.